# Need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\frac 1{(n!)^\frac 1{n}}$

Tags: limits

I've attempted to solve this  $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\frac 1{(n!)^\frac 1{n}}$ via converging 1/n to zero, but somehow it's incorrect. Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: use stirling approximation to write n!

Comment: Thank's for your reply, but i know that it can be solved without stirling approximation. I mean, i can't rely on it every time

Comment: use logarithms and convert it into an integral

Comment: Also tried and it worked, but still there is solution via squeeze theorem.

Comment: Then you have elaborate it in your question well. you must be getting the answer as 1(using squeeze thm), right?

Comment: You' re right, next time i'll write it down in description. The correct answer is 0

Comment: Use $$\frac{x^{x}}{e^{x}}<x!<x^{x}$$ for $x>1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$0<\frac 1{(n!)^\frac 1{n}}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}}<\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n}\to 0.$$
In general, we have: if $a_n\to a$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}=a.$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, however this approach is not obvious. How can we prove the part with < inequality?

Comment: the inequality used is AM-GM inequality! And you can refer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality

Comment: AM-GM inequality is an elementary inequality even for high school students! You should master it (learn to use it).

Answer (score 2):

The limit is $0$, and the following very hands-on argument suffices: for any positive integer $k \le n$ we have

$$n! \ge k^{n-k}$$

(we look at $1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot n$ and just ignore the terms less than or equal to $k$ and replace all the terms bigger than $k$ with $k$), which gives

$$\sqrt[n]{n!} \ge k^{1 - \frac{k}{n}}.$$

Taking, for example, $k = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ gives

$$\sqrt[n]{n!} \ge \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n!} = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} = 0$. Of course much tighter bounds are available, and even quite exact asymptotics via [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_formula), but it's worth knowing what can be proven in a very elementary way.

Comment: I like this one, but how can we proove that n! is actually more than k^n-k

Comment: @Amil: I gave the argument in parentheses: you look at the product $1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot n$, ignore the terms less than or equal to $k$, and bound the terms greater than or equal to $k$ by $k$. It's very simple.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{(n!)^\frac 1{n}}$$

$$\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{1}{n}\ln(n!)$$

$$\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{1}{n}\left({\ln1+\ln2+\cdots\ln n}\right)$$

$$\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{1}{n}\left({[\ln\frac{1}{n}+\ln\frac{2}{n}+\cdots\ln\frac{n}{n}]+n\ln n}\right)$$

$$\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({\int_0^1\ln x dx-\ln n}\right)$$

$$\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({-1-\ln n}\right)\to-\infty$$

$$y=e^{-\infty}\to0$$

Comment: How did you convert the rienman sum into integral without a $ \frac{1}{n}..?$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3761414/688539)

Comment: @Buraian Yep, an error there

Answer (score -1):

Use the common limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^\frac 1n = \lim_{n \to \infty} n \times \frac{1}{(n!)^\frac1n} = e$$
It's easy to see that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(n!)^\frac1n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e}{n} = 0$$

And that's the final answer.

---

It's easier to do this via Stirling's approximation, as $n! = \sqrt{2\pi n}\left( \frac ne\right)^n$ and the nth root of $1/n!$ is equal to $e/n$, which tends to 0.